# Render UI R shiny dashboard issue

Tags: r, shiny

I'm having an issue with my renderUI code. 
I wanted my shiny dashboard to be interactive to the user where he/she can select a particular dataset. Now given the datasets have the same set of variables and order, I don't know why my code won't work.

I'm having an issue with my Server code with the key work "bar". I've set "bar" to define the dataset the user has chosen but i keep getting this Error:"error object of type 'closure' is not subsettable".

The only way my code to work so far is if I edit the "bar" to a fix dataset, but that would defeat the purpose of my dashboard being "interactive"

Here are my codes for UI and Server:

```
UI:
#selecting the dataset
selectInput("dataset",label="Select the dataset of your choice", choices= c("January_2016","February_2016"),selectize = TRUE)
```

Server:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) ({

     bar<- reactive({
       switch(input$dataset,
              "January_2016" = names(January_2016),
              "February_2016" = names(February_2016))
     })

     output$vx <- renderUI({
       selectInput("variable","Select variable", choices=bar())
     })

#trying to calculate something where the column 2 of the selected data set should satisfy the condition 
     output$DPMO <- renderUI({
       valueBox(format(sum(bar[which(bar[,2]== "APAC - SENA"),14])/(length(which(bar[,2]== "APAC - ANZ"))*15)*1000000,digits=2,nsmall=0) , "DPMO of APAC - ANZ", width = 3)
     })
```

Comment: `bar` holds the names of your dataframes, maybe replace `names(January_2016)` by `January_2016`,same for the other one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. still got the same error: error object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.

Comment: You also need to use `bar()` to get the data frame. `bar` is a closure (function) which is why you get this error. `bar()` will return your reactive data frame.

Comment: The problem lies in `output $DPMO <-`. You make several references to `bar`, but I don't think those should even be `bar()`. `bar()` is a character vector, but it seems you want to use a data frame there. At least, I think. I'm not really sure what that call is supposed to do. But I have my doubts that it will do what you are intending.